# jQuery on will not work with a class

Tags: jquery

This simple jQuery will not work for me when using `on`. Is there another method to use `on`? Will `on` not work with a `class`. I'm using `jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.3`

I'm trying to move some old code from `live()` to `on()`.

```
$(".subUser").on("click",function() {
  alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});

<div class="container">
    <div><i class="icon-add subUser"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you adding your .subUser element dynamically?

Comment: ok then use event delegation as explained by Adil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems alright if you do not add elements with class `subUser` dynamically. You probably need to put in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".subUser").on("click",function() {
     alert("The paragraph was clicked.");  
  });
});
```

If you are adding elements dynamically then you need event delegation. You have to use the parent element in selector which is present at the time your bind code gets executed or you can use document or body.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", ".subUser", function() {
     alert("The paragraph was clicked.");  
  });
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: +1 Oh gosh, I remember when I first started using jQuery, event delegation with newly appended elements drove me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

You can change to this then:

```
$(".container").on("click", ".subUser" ,function() {
```

As you are moved your code from `.live()` to `.on()` then you have to delegate the event to the static parent which was available before the dom change.

so in your case it seems that `.container` class was available at that point of time then you have to delegate to that or you can delegate to `$(document)` directly because document always available to delegate the event(*`this might be little slower`*).

Answer (score 0):

check this how you should replace your code

```
        // Bind
        $( "#members li a" ).on( "click", function( e ) {} );
        $( "#members li a" ).bind( "click", function( e ) {} );

        // Live
        $( document ).on( "click", "#members li a", function( e ) {} );
        $( "#members li a" ).live( "click", function( e ) {} );

        // Delegate
        $( "#members" ).on( "click", "li a", function( e ) {} );
        $( "#members" ).delegate( "li a", "click", function( e ) {} );
```

REFERENCE

http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html